# Discord.py bot connection with MongoDB not working

Tags: python, mongodb, discord

Im currently creating an economy discord.py bot and im quite new to using Databases.
Ive made a simple command to create an account for the user in the database. Heres the code:

```
import discord, os, requests, json, random, time, datetime, pymongo
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
import urllib
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Member,app_commands
from discord.ui import Select, Button, View

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="c!", intents=intents, activity=activity)
bot.remove_command("help")
uri = "mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@mycluster.vfoyaox.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority" 
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
db = client["cluster0"]
collection = db.users

try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

@bot.command()
async def createaccount(ctx):
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    username = ctx.author.name
    collection.insert_one({
        "discord_id": user_id,
        "discord_username": username,
        "discord_balance": 100
    })
    await ctx.send("Your account has been created with a starting balance of 100 credits.")
```

It prints out:

bad auth : authentication failed, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : authentication failed', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}

from print(e).

It doesnt really show any error, other than that because it was printed, but when I run the command in discord, nothing gets printed.

I alredy troubleshooted it, and found out that it stops after the collection.insert_one, and I assume its probably something wrong with the connection with MongoDB. I also made sure that my uri is correct.

Im very new to databases and I have absolutely no experience with them, so theres probably alot of problems in my code.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470